# When attaching jpeg to SMTP mail message, why is the image "blank" when I receive it? What is wrong with this code?

Tags: c#, .net, image, smtp, email-attachments

I have the following code which attaches a jpeg to an email.

```
System.Net.Mime.ContentType contentType = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType();
contentType.MediaType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg;
contentType.Name = "screen";

Attachment screenCapture = new Attachment(imageStream, contentType);

//this next line works, I checked the image on the hard drive so I know the jpeg is ok
File.WriteAllBytes("c:\\somecoolimage.jpeg", imageStream.ToArray());

mail.Attachments.Add(screenCapture);

smtp.Send(mail);
```

However, when I get the email with the attachment in my email, it has 0 bytes. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you've left `imageStream` positioned at the *end* of the data instead of at the *start*? (I'm assuming it's a `MemoryStream`.) Try this:

```
imageStream.Position = 0;
Attachment screenCapture = new Attachment(imageStream, contentType);
```

(`MemoryStream.ToArray` ignores the current position of the stream, but I suspect that `Attachment` doesn't.)

Comment: That did the trick. I really need to get a better understanding of streams. Thanks Jon.